# Draw Rectangle using Wpf in a 3D space

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF 3D Drawing. I am trying to draw a rectangle in the 3D C# WPF.

How to draw this using the following parameter

```
DrawRectangle(double x, double z, double width, double height)
```

where z is distance of that rectangle from perspective camera.

How to Draw an overlay over frames using Classes like ViewPort3D and Perspective Camera ?

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRadL.png)

Comment: I having a hard time with this also, since if we deal with 3D we are talking with rectangles

Comment: Hi Katana..
Did you have any relative link in regard of this problem...is it possible that without using spaceline3d we can create a transparent rectangle with only border in 3D drawing....

Comment: Do you want rectangle in top of 3D (camera direction independent = 2D) or inside 3D (real 3D flat 4 black rectangles - one for each edge)?

Comment: Rectangle will be camera dependent..inside 3d only..

Answer (score 0):

my requirement is to draw some shapes like rectangle on a bitmap image (Which is coming from a vehicle sensor camera) where we have the object position in real world and camera parameters are given.

Eg:
Object positions.........
Long Pos (m)    13.560760
Lat Pos (m) 0.33948556
Width (m)   1.7295655
Height (m)  1.5668937

camera parameters......
    Horizon/pitch   = -44 pixels / -0.0008976 m
    Yaw/pan = 12 pixels / 0.0002448 m
    Roll Angle  = 0.0 radians
    Focal Length    = 1458 pixels / 0.0297432 m
    Pixels per Degree   = 24.615385 
    Camera Height (above ground)    = 1.27 m
    Camera Long Pos (from vehicle front)    = -1.703 m
    Camera Lat Pos (from vehicle center)    = 0.0 m

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. Please take some time and look at some tips on improving your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).